# Redis (grails plugin) does not persist Enum Object

Tags: grails, enums, redis

I've got a grails domain class I have to persist in Redis, something like this:

```
class A {
    String one
    Integer two

    B three

    E four

    mapWith = "redis"
}

class B {
    String name
}

enum E {
   VALUE1, VALUE2
}
```

When I persist an instance of class A with the GORM .save() method, Redis saves it correctly except for the enum field "four".

As you can see the fact is known and reported here: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPREDIS-3

Is there a good workaround to save Enum or something similar? 
We're thinking about an array of String objects, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got this mostly implemented but it doesn't work for Gemfire and I'm waiting until it's fixed for all the supported nosql providers before pushing the fix. As a workaround you can use the `inList` constraint with a combination of a persistent `String` property and a non-persistent get/set pair with the name of your current property, e.g.

```
class A {
   String one
   Integer two

   B three

   String fourString

   void setFour(E e) {
      fourString = e?.name()
   }
   E getFour() {
      fourString ? E.valueOf(fourString) : null
   }

   static constraints = {
      fourString inList: E.values()*.name()
   }

   static transients = ['fourString']

   static mapWith = "redis"
}
```

Comment: To make this work, I have removed the "transients" mapping, otherwise the getter wasn't able to retrieve the field by the in-fact-not-persisted corresponding string.

Am i doing it wrong someway? Why did you indicate to put the string as a transient field?

Comment: Sorry, should be 'four' since that's just a get/set pair.